# Control what want to drag and drop from object

Tags: javascript, angular, sortablejs

I use ngx-sortableJS for drag and drop.

I have "tools" div from where I take (drag) items and drop zone div.

My items in tools are objects, I need this data object to show icon and img in tools div

```
cons tools = [
{ name: 'tool1', data: { icon: 'text_fields', type: 'tools' } },
{ name: 'tool2', data: { icon: 'text_fields', type: 'tools' } },
{ name: 'tool3', data: { icon: 'text_fields', type: 'tools' } },
]
```

Now I want, when I drag some of this item, to take and drop the only NAME from the dropped object

```
{ name: 'tool1' }
```

Is there a way to control what we want to drag and drop, or we need to always drop the whole object?

here is [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q2owek?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Thnx

Comment: @JohnPeters angular CDK don't have all features what I need for this. Thnx

Comment: Do you need to move the element from the first list to the second one or just add a new item in the second one?
Do you need to move from the second list to the first one as well?

Also, do you know that Angular has a structural type system so that you can write `this.normalList2.push(this.normalList1[0]);`? So I do not see why the DnD feature of Angular does not work here.

Comment: Hi, i need to move from first list to second list.